# SQL: How to add a NULL value into the table and bypass the constraint check?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE user (
  user_id   INT,
  user_name VARCHAR(100),
  CONSTRAINT pk_user_id PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);
```

How can I bypass the constraint and add a new user with `NULL` id?

```
INSERT INTO user (user_id, user_name) VALUES (NULL, 'John');
```

Would this be at all possible? Maybe there is some hack or something.

Comment: Why would you want a constraint that can be bypassed?

Comment: I'm just learning SQL and want to know some tricks around it.

Comment: Remove the `primary key` constraint.  If the column can take a `NULL` value, then it is not a primary key.

Comment: Maybe I can do that insert if I write some stored procedure/trigger to avoid constraint check? Is it possible?

Comment: No, because primary keys cannot have `NULL` values.

Comment: Even some smart database trigger couldn't help with it?

Comment: Primary key values need to be unique and not `NULL`; those are [the rules](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/ddl-constraints.html) and there is no way around it. Lift the constraint if you need to allow `NULL` values.

Comment: No. There is no way to circumvent it.

Comment: In fact, if you could do that then it'd be a bug. PostgreSQL *relies* on the fact that there can't be nulls in a `NOT NULL` column when planning queries; it also uses the knowledge that `UNIQUE` columns are in fact unique. Why would you possibly want to do this anyway? What are you attempting to achieve with this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use null values in column that meant to be unique, then use unique index instead of primary key.

It will allow you to store any number of rows with null user_id in it (just because null <> null). So be careful.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, with the table defined as listed.

You can't change the fact that a primary key cannot accept NULL as a value, but you could alter the table and make that field not be a primary key.